# html2canvas not rendering CDN images

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I'm trying to get screenshot using html2canvas. It's working fine for text but it is not rendering CDN images, if i host the images in server it was working fine but if trying to load images from CDN links those image were not rendering.

My code is:

index.php

```
<div id="target">
     <img id="editor_Img_1" src="http://d2j259rizy5u5h.cloudfront.net/outputvideos/thumbs/email_44_2015_03_02_54f462457526c-00001.png" alt="event-video" style="height: 200px; width: 320px;">
</div>

function capture() {
    $('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(img);
            $('<img>',{src:img}).appendTo($('img'));
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Save.php

```
<?php
    //Get the base-64 string from data
    $filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

    //Decode the string
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    echo $filteredData;

    //Save the image
    file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);
?>
<h2>Save the image and show to user</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="img.png" target="blank">
            Click Here to See The Image Saved to Server</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a href="index.php">
            Click Here to Go Back</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>
            Here is Client-sided image:
        </span>
        <br />
        <?php
            //Show the image
            echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';
        ?>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: More than likely there's a cross-domain request in there somewhere, which is forbidden.  Check your JavaScript console for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, well I figured out what the problem is. html2canvas can't capture an image if it's not from the same origin. Images are coming from a CDN. There are some limitation to html to canvas

**Limitations**

All the images that the script uses need to reside under the **[same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)** for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a **[proxy](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#)**. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty and no longer readable by html2canvas.

The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java applets. It doesn't render iframe content either.

[Documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html)

Comment: Did you ever work out a solution to this? I have come across the same issue - and putting everything onto a non CDN domain seems a bit overkill!

Comment: @Bhavin Solanki did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by passing one of the option in html2canvas function.

```
html2canvas(document.body,
{
   useCORS: true, //By passing this option in function Cross origin images will be rendered properly in the downloaded version of the PDF
   onrendered: function (canvas) {
     //your functions here
   }
});
```

Comment: {Very helpful}.